# How can I use regex to replace variables by their value in a calculation string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a calculator with variables, but where the variables and the calculation are defined by the user. I've made a program to get all that stuff, but now I want to replace the variables by their values in the calculation.

To be sure to do not replace only a part for a variable (for example if I have 'm' and 'm1' defined, I don't want to replace the m in 'm1' by 'm' value), I have to respect the following conditions :

- Before the variable's name, there is either an opening bracket, or an operation
- After the variable's name, there is either an closing bracket, or an operation

The space are removed when I get the calculation (I've not included that feature yet)

To do so, I have made the following code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) 
{
    regex = "(\+|\-|\*|\/|\()" + names[i].value + "(\+|\-|\*|\/|\))"
    replacement = "$1" + values[i].value + "$2"
    calculation = calculation.replace(regex, replacement)
}
```

For example, for the variable 'm', I get the regex : `(\+|\-|\*|/|\()m(\+|\-|\*|/|\))`

The problem is that nothing is found (I've tried with `(m+n+x)`). I know the problem comes from the regex but I can't find it.

Comment: I just forgot to write the ```(``` and ```)``` at the beginning and the end of the calculation. I've escaped the ```/``` but that doesn't change anything

Comment: How could I fix that ? (for the time being, I have just been using regex in PHP and C++, never in JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `regex` isn't being treated as a regular expression, but rather just a normal `string`.

Instead, turn it into a `new RegExp()`. Note that a single `\` in your pattern string will be removed (as this is the standard escape character), so you'll need to "double-escape" them.

```js
const names =  [{value: "a"}, {value: "b"}];
const values = [{value:  1 }, {value:  5 }];
let calculation = "(a+b)";

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) 
{
    const pattern = "(\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/|\\()" + names[i].value + "(\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/|\\))";
    const regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    const replacement = "$1" + values[i].value + "$2"
    calculation = calculation.replace(regex, replacement)
}

console.log(calculation);
```